# Logstash-logback event-specific custom fields (using StructuredArguments) are not added to JSON

Tags: java, logstash, logback

I'm trying to add event-specific field to one of the logger statements using [logstash documentation](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#event-specific-custom-fields). My logger statement is following:

```
LOGGER.info("Executed REST request time={}ms", StructuredArguments.value("request_time_ms", elapsedTimeMs));
```

According to documentation:

> **StructuredArguments will be included in the JSON output if using LogstashEncoder**/Layout or if using composite encoders/layouts with the arguments provider

That means `StructuredArguments` should work fine for me as long as I'm using `LogstashEncoder`:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

But still `request_time_ms` is missing in output JSON:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2018-09-20T14:00:43.560+03:00",
    "@version": 1,
    "appname": "my_app",
    "level": "INFO",
    "level_value": 20000,
    "logger_name": "com.example.MetricsAspect",
    "message": "Executed REST request time=258ms",
    "thread_name": "main"
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears that `StructuredArguments` won't be included in JSON even if you use `LogstashEncoder` until you explicitly add `ArgumentsJsonProvider`:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <provider class="net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.ArgumentsJsonProvider"/>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Now it works as expected:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2018-09-20T15:43:11.019+03:00",
    "@version": 1,
    "appname": "my_app",
    "level": "INFO",
    "level_value": 20000,
    "logger_name": "com.example.MetricsAspect",
    "message": "Executed REST request time=337ms",
    "request_time_ms": 337,
    "thread_name": "main"
}
```

Comment: Can you post what dependancy and versions you are using. Like versions of "logstash-logback-encoder", "logback-classic", "jackson-core", "jackson-databind"

Comment: @Abhishek my current setup is: net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:5.2, ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2

Comment: @bsiamionau I tried these steps with the same dependencies but it's not working. Is there anything that could be missing here?

Comment: @elixir, that was enough for solving my problem, nothing else. have you found the reason?

Comment: @bsiamionau It seems that it doesn't directly work with dropwizard framework.